# Use of Bootstrap classes in container tag

Tags: moqui

I am trying to make a responsive screen. I have used bootstrap classes in this way:

```
<container style="row">
  <container style="col-md-4">
    <label text="Demo text one"/>
  </container>
  <container style="col-md-4">
    <label text="Demo text two"/>
  </container>
  <container style="col-md-4">
    <label text="Demo text three"/>
  </container>
</container>
```

I got reference of this from dashboard.xml from Hivemind component.

Is it a correct way of using bootstrap classes to achieve responsiveness in Moqui? 
Since, I remember a similar question where we have discussed it as not an appropriate way to code. Here is the URL or that question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502820/what-are-the-possible-ways-to-make-an-ui-interface-using-moqui-framework

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many sets of styles that are useful from Bootstrap for UI that is responsive to screen size. This isn't so much a Moqui questions as a Bootstrap one, and fortunately they have great documentation (see also the Components, JavaScript, and other pages there):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Note that Moqui currently uses quite a few of the Bootstrap styles, and is slowly being changed to use more over time, including a number of changes still not released in the current GitHub repository (for version 1.5.0).